# Create a folder that is not accessible by anyone?

Tags: android, android-file

I want to create a folder that no one can access except me from my app, I mean no user can open the folder and use its contents. And I am not talking about adding a `.` before the name of the directory.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: That is really not possible. The owner of the device can always gain control of things on the device.

Comment: @mrunion so I cant encrypt a folder?

Comment: Certainly, you can encrypt the content of the folder. File by file, or create a zipfile containing several files and encrypt the zipfile.

Comment: @Barns so if the files are videos then no one can access them from out side the appif they are encrypted?

Comment: @Barns even rooted devices wont access without key?

Comment: Encrypted is encrypted. AES encryption is quite secure. Someone would really want to get at your data if they were going to attempt decrypting your data

Comment: So i do this from code when I create the folder and give it key, and is this supported on all android versions?

Comment: All Android devices can incorporate encryption. Have a look at  these namespaces and do a little research on the web:: import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

Comment: @Barns thanks for your help.

Comment: Encryption is really quite easy--basically just writing/reading to/from a stream. None of the two methods mentioned below are in anyway secure! That is just writing a simple file.

Comment: @Barns so your advice is that I should go with encryption for ultimate security?

Comment: No one can provide ultimate security, but I feel quite safe using AES encryption on my device to prevent almost anyone from reading any sensitive data I might want to save on my device. Just be certain that you keep the encryption key secure. BTW: writing to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` is standard procedure. It is not really a security feature.

Comment: @Barns thanks for providing me with this info.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage) described in the Android doc?

> Files saved here are accessible by only your app.

However, this way cannot prevent root user from reading your files. You probably need to encrypt it to provide better security.

Comment: Even if I saved to internal storage, then a user can browse the files using file manager....how is that secure?

Comment: Normal users cannot access it using file manager. If you have to prevent root users. That could be a very complicated task(may even involve a server). As for encryption, it's a too big question, a simple way is to find a handy encryption library(for example, from here https://android-arsenal.com/tag/87?sort=rating).

Answer (score 2):

I think we can't lock a directory from the root user. 
For creating a file by restricting access use the following code,

```
String FILENAME = "demo.txt";
String string = "Hello World";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: This will prevent opening a file? And should this be done using a file output stream?

Comment: Can I create a file directly and make it mode private...then add stuff to it without output stream?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
applicationContext.getFilesDir()
```

All content that will be saved in this directory will be accessible only from your app.